# jQuery Sortable to enable input

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, post

I have 2 divs. The 1st div `Available items` contains some list items which contains an input field which is set to `disabled`, which can be dragged into the other `Wanted items` div. This works fine, but I need to enable the input once it is in the wanted items list so that when I post that it only posts the items which was in wanted and not everything. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should specify a function in the `receive` method on the wanted items list. Something like:

```
$("#wantedItems").sortable({
    receive: function (event, ui) {
        //enable the input here
    }
});
```